# How to display data in a matrix

Tags: linq

I have a query that returns Countries and Sectors and percentages for each country by sector in a matrix format. I can't seem to find a linq query that will return the data to display in this format. My data from the database looks like this:

```
Canada | Education | 20
Canada | Medical   | 80
Mexico | Education | 40
Mexico | Medical   | 60
```

and I need to display it like this:

```
                   Education | Medical
Canada                 20    |    80
Mexico                 40    |    60
```

I need to group on the Country but display the Sectors as columns. Here is my query:

```
var query = from p in ctx.Programs
                      group p by p.Country.Name into g
                      select new
                      {
                          rowKey = g.Key,
                          rowData = g.Select(s => new { Sector = s.Sector.NameEng, Percentage = s.BUDGET_PCT })
                      };
            return query;
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: how do you check if it's education or medical?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"? Is there an error, or you just get blank values?

Comment: Assuming it can get past the `p.Country.Name` line, a preemptive suggestion would be to try `ctx.Programs.Include("Sector")`

Comment: @Keyur PATEL Sorry, I omitted some important details. The query seems to return the correct details. I get 2 country records and each record has a list of Sectors and associated Percentages. I have this query in a method but I'm not sure how to return it to my Controller so I can map it to a viewModel property. It's an anonymous query and I'm not sure what the return type would be or if I should create a class to hold these values.Once I map it to my viewModel, how do you display this in Html?

Comment: @Thiago Custodio each record has a lookup value for the country and the sector so I know which sector is associated to which country.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. I created a class that has 2 properties, one to hold the rowKey and one to hold the List for rowData and then I created a class for the rowData. I returned that and then added this to the Html and it displays the Matrix properly:

```
<table id="tblMatrix">
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            @foreach (var cs in Model.CountrySectors.FirstOrDefault().SectorList)
                            {
                                <th>@cs.Sector</th>
                            }
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var cs in Model.CountrySectors)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@cs.Country</td>
                                @foreach (var s in cs.SectorList)
                                {
                                    <td>@s.Percentage</td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
```

and this works. Hope it helps someone out there.